# Looking for the design pattern - DI explosion

Tags: design-patterns

I am preparing for interviews and as I was doing interview questions in many topics, got different projects I decided to refactor a little the project as its not scaling well.

The structure of the solution is something as follow, below enumeration are the projects.

1. Arrays
2. SortingAlgorithms
3. Trees
4. Linkedlists
5. etc

My problem is with displaying the results, I want to make it as minimal as possible:

I have the following classes and interfaces:

`IDisplay`

```
public interface IDisplay<T>
{
    void DisplayResult(T[] array);
    void DisplayResult(T[][] matrix);
    void DisplayResult(TreeNode treeNode);
    void DisplayResult(IList<T> treeNodes);
    void DisplayResult(T value);
    void DisplayNewLine();
}
```

`Display` implements the `IDisplay`, implementation is not important at this point.

Then I have a `DI` explosion in the `Tests`

```
    private readonly IDisplay<TreeNode> _display;
    private readonly IDisplay<string> _displayText;
    private readonly IDisplay<int> _displayList;
    private readonly IDisplay<char> _displayChar;
    private readonly IDisplay<bool> _displayBool;

    public Tests(IDisplay<TreeNode> display,
        IDisplay<int> displayList,
        IDisplay<string> displayText,
        IDisplay<char> displayChar,
        IDisplay<bool> displayBool,
        IFreeCodeCampBinaryTrees freeCodeCampBinaryTrees,
        ILeetCodeTrees leetCode,
        TreeTraversal treeTraversal)
    {
        _display = display;
        _displayText = displayText;
        _displayChar = displayChar;
        _displayList = displayList;
        _displayBool = displayBool;
        _freeCodeCampBinaryTrees = freeCodeCampBinaryTrees;
        _leetCode = leetCode;
        _treeTraversal = treeTraversal;
        TreeNode = _freeCodeCampBinaryTrees.InitializeTree3();
        TreeNodeOfChars = _freeCodeCampBinaryTrees.InitializeTree4();
    }

    // Methods look like this
    public void ValueExistsBFS(TreeNode root)
    {
        _displayBool.DisplayResult(_freeCodeCampBinaryTrees.ValueExistsBFS(root, 3));
    }

    public void PostOrderTraversalIterative(TreeNodeOfChar root)
     {
         _displayText.DisplayResult("Postorder Traversal - Iterative");
         _displayChar.DisplayResult(_treeTraversal.PostorderTraversalIterativeOfChars(root));
     }
```

And I have another class where I instantiate the actual `Display` and I run all tests in one method:

```
public class BinaryTreesTestRunner
{
    private Tests _tests;
    private TreeNode _head;
    private TreeNodeOfChar _headOfChars;

    public BinaryTreesTestRunner()
    {
        _tests = new Tests(new Display<TreeNode>(), 
                            new Display<int>(), 
                            new Display<string>(), 
                            new Display<char>(), 
                            new Display<bool>(), 
                            new FreeCodeCampBinaryTrees(), 
                            new LeetCodeTrees(), 
                            new TreeTraversal());
        _head = _tests.TreeNode;
        _headOfChars = _tests.TreeNodeOfChars;
    }
```

As you can see in constructor, I have the similar issue with trees, here I need to make a tree of int or char, it didn't exploded yet but is the same issue.

I tried two things which I think are wrong and I don't waste rest of the day doing another bad implementation, its better to ask first.

1. I tried having a class where I get the type of `T` and use a switch to instantiate `Display` then I was thinking to inject that class in the constructors but many comments were against that.
2. I tried factory pattern but then I realized I will need to have a `DisplayBool`, `DisplayString` which will implement same methods with a different type.

What I am really looking for is: have a class where I instantiate all the different types,
inject that class in a constructor, then I can have `_display.DisplayResult(accepts any type)`, I am ok with `_display<sometype>.DisplayResult(param)`, I am not ok with `displayBool.DisplayResult(bool)`

Like I don't need some free code, I need some logic, the right design pattern than can accomplish this, I am gonna do the research, I just feel like `Factory Pattern` is close but not there.

EDIT:
For a temporary solution, I just create a class and I instantiate in the constructor `Display` class with all types I need. I really hope there is a better way

Comment: why not just having the class Tests as template with single parameter constructor ? the existence of all the types at the same time does not do anything therefore is not needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like we have the same goal for various types and the goal is to display results. What differs is just types of result. Basically, it can be considered that it is necessary to have various approaches, strategies to display results which can have different types. I believe that Strategy pattern can be used. As wiki says about [Strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern):

> In computer programming, the strategy pattern (also known as the
> policy pattern) is a behavioral software design pattern that enables
> selecting an algorithm at runtime. Instead of implementing a single
> algorithm directly, code receives run-time instructions as to which in
> a **family of algorithms to use**

Let me show an example via C#.

Let's create our enums for `ResultType`:

```
public enum ResultType
{
    Array,
    Matrix,
    TreeNode
}
```

And using the above enums it would be perfect case to create a simple factory. Simple factory is not [Factory method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) and not [Abstract factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern). To be honest, there is no pattern like *simple factory*. At least, canonical book by GoF does not describe a such pattern.

```
public class DisplayFactory<T>
{
    private Dictionary<ResultType, IDisplay<T>> _displayByResultType = new()
    {
        { ResultType.Array, new DisplayArray<T>() },
        { ResultType.Matrix, new DisplayMatrix<T>() },
        { ResultType.TreeNode, new DisplayTreeNode<T>() },
    };
    
    public IDisplay<T> GetInstanceByLibrary(ResultType resultType) =>
        _displayByResultType[resultType];
}
```

And then our abstraction of `Display` class looks like this:

```
public interface IDisplay<T>
{
    void Display(MyResult<T> result);
}
```

and `MyResult` will contain all necessary types to show:

```
public class MyResult<T>
{
    public T[] Array { get; set; }

    public T[][] Matrix { get; set; }

    public IList<T> TreeNodes { get; set; }
}
```

Then out concrete implentations of `IDisplay<T>`:

```
public class DisplayArray<T> : IDisplay<T>
{
    public void Display(MyResult<T> argument)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Display of Array is run");
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class DisplayMatrix<T> : IDisplay<T>
{
    public void Display(MyResult<T> argument)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class DisplayTreeNode<T> : IDisplay<T>
{
    public void Display(MyResult<T> argument)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And then it is possible to create a helper method to get instance of `Display` class:

```
IDisplay<T> CreateByResultType<T>(ResultType resultType)
{
    DisplayFactory<T> displayFactory = new();
    return displayFactory.GetInstanceByLibrary(resultType);
}
```

and then the code snippet of calling code would look pretty nice:

```
MyResult<int> myResult = new MyResult<int>() { Array = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }  };
IDisplay<int> displayArray = CreateByResultType<int>(ResultType.Array);
displayArray.Display(myResult);
```

Moreover, this design is compliant with the [open/closed principle](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/19627/clarify-the-open-closed-principle).

Comment: I actually came up yesterday with some sort of solution. I got a class that contains all `IDisplay` types, and I instantiate the `Display` in the constructor, then I inject this class in constructors where I need then I have `_display.DisplayBoolean.DisplayResult(..stuff..)`, look ugly but at least I moved away from that `DI` mess in each class.  I am gonna take a look at your solution, but it seems really what I wanted, if you got the time I can share the github repo, I will tell you where to look. PS. I have read Head First and Gang of Four, still practice outside the books comes different..